# Возможно ли OrthographicCamera в libgdx настроить так, чтобы вместо всего экрана она применялась к конкретной области экрана?

Tags: java, libgdx, камера, экран

Возможно ли OrthographicCamera в libgdx настроить так, чтобы вместо всего экрана она применялась к конкретной области экрана? То есть важно, чтобы вся система координат, заданная мною, работала внутри этой области, чтобы все элементы рисовались внутри этой области и чтобы viewport также обрезал или масштабировал внутри этой области

Answer (score 0):

В общем, определился.
Например, если мой экран 300 на 300, а область находится в точке 100х100 и размером 100х100, а внутри области система координат, например, 500х500, то я вычисляю коэффициент - во сколько раз система координат отличается от размера экрана, то есть 500/100 для ширины и 500/100 для высоты, потом создаю камеру размером 300*5 для ширины и 300*5 для высоты, и передвигаю камеру в позицию, в которой начинается система координат моей области: 100*5 для ширины и 100*5 для высоты. В коде это выглядит так:

```
float k_width=width/this.width, k_height=height/this.height;
this.camera.setToOrtho(false, screenWidth*k_width,
    screenHeight*k_height);
this.camera.translate(-x*k_width, -y*k_height);
```

А вот как настроить viewport, прикреплённый к камере, я пока не разобрался

Comment: Нет, это оказался плохой способ, потому что тот же самый zoom работает относительно центра экрана, а не области центра экрана